# Is there a single word for "taking a blindfold off" someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single word that I can use in place of "taking the blindfold off" of someone. I thought of unmasking, but I think of that as revealing what something looks like to other people. I want to emphasize that this person can now see. Is there a good word for this?

Answer (score 4):

There is, of course, ***unblindfold.***

Even though *un-* is productive and can generally be prefixed to many words to reverse the action, there is actually an entry in OED:

> unblindfold, *v.*
>
> *transitive.* To unbandage (the eyes); to free (a person or animal) from a bandage over the eyes. Also *figurative.*

It has a venerable heritage and is neither a neologism nor the result of laziness.

> c1430   *Pilgr. Lyf Manhode* (1869) iv. xix. 186   Þat þei vnblyndfelle so here eyen þat þei mown biholde to þe heuene.

Comment: This seems the best option, due to having the exact meaning requested. If for some reason the word is too ugly/long/etc, you could also use *unblinker* or *unmask* which don't mean quite the same thing but both have a connotation of removing an impediment to vision.